# How to do parallel / background task in Flask

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi

Would you can help me with parallel task. I am doing this for few days and I have any more ideas.
I would like run `main()` task on background continuos for check temperature a control outputs.

When I start webserver, function `main()` do only one cycle and flask `app()` is running right.

Thank you very much.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
import datetime
import time
from random import random
from random import seed
import threading
from pytz import utc
import atexit

app = Flask(__name__)
myThread = threading.Thread()
POOL_TIME = 5 #seconds

@app.route('/')
def index():
        return render_template('index.html', **templateData)

@app.route("/<deviceName>/<action>")
def action(deviceName, action):
        return render_template('index.html', **templateData)

def main():
        print('Init main task on background')
        time.sleep(1)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
        #myThread = threading.Timer(POOL_TIME, main, ())
        #myThread.start()
        threading.Thread(target = main()).start()
        app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
        #app.run(threaded=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with the "main" code in a thread (I've not included all the imports that you will need - your code obviously needs to include the ones you already have):

```
import threading

class MonitorThread(threading.Thread):

     def run(self):
          debug_log("Monitor system thread")

          try:
               while 1: # Monitor the system forever while powered
                   print('Init main task on background')
                   # ... Add here whatever you want to do forever
                   time.sleep(1)
          except KeyboardInterrupt:
               GPIO.cleanup()

MonitorThread().start()

app = Flask(__name__) # Start webpage

# Flask web page code

@app.route("/")
def index():
# ... Include all of your Flask web page code generation

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(debug=False, host="0.0.0.0")
```

If that doesn't work then let me know as my app is quite complicated but does run forever and serve webpages as requested so it'll only be because I have omitted something.

Answer (score 1):

Your main function doesn't loop so it will only execute once. You need to add a loop, such as:

```
def main():
    while 1 :
        print('Init main task on background')
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: But this solution is not on background. It only be in infinity loop and never go to next command.

This will not be execute:
app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')

Comment: Sorry I didn't spot that. I don't know if what I am about to write is the best way... but the way I have my apps using Flask laid out is that in in your last if statement I only have the app.run line. Apps that I've written then use threads for things that run in the background. It'll be easiest if I start a new answer and cut-paste bits out of an example app.